# Isolation during unit testing and duplicate code for test data

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I am working on some application in Java and writing JUnit tests. I have a design question about Unit Testing. I have one class that reads a file and Create object called **Song** by reading different lines and parsing based on some algorithm. I have written some unit test on that. Next step after parsing is to actually convert that song to a different format based on some properties of **Song** object. I have another class that works as a translator. There is a method translate that takes **Song** object as input. Now in unit test for translator. I need a Song object with all valid properties. I am confused here that should I create a new **Song** object by putting same functionality as in parser or should I call the parser service to do that for me. I feel it will not be isolated if I take the second option. But in first option it's like duplicate code. Can somebody guide  me on this?

Comment: Why can't you just create a song by invoking its constructor and then call your translateor? Why would you need to read a file just to create a new Song object?

Comment: @JBNizet I understand your comment but Song object is not a simple object with some name and id like properties. It has some String that reflects digital signal as well. Algorithm coverts this digital signal to a particular string. And creating that string without algorithm so that translator can translate it correctly is hard and probably dirty. In case something will change tomorrow the way we generate digital to string. Updating translator test will be a mess and Its hard to maintain as well.

Comment: OK. Then I would put a test file in the test sources and parse it to create a test song. Sure, your test would also rely on the parser, but I don't see any better solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong in using a Builder in order to create the input data for a SUT invocation when this data is complex, however I see 2 risks here.

- If the builder fails your test will fail too, but it shouldn't. As you said unit tests should be isolated from external code.
- If you use code coverage as a metric to evaluate how good your unit tests are (I don't mean this is right), by looking at the builder's coverage you'll be tempted to think it's tested though obviously isn't.

My opinion is there's not a best solution fitting all the scenarios. In case the input data is not very complex try to build it "manually", otherwise use the builder.